# Problems with a button tag on IE7 styled with a sprite, inline-block and text-indent -9999px

Tags: css

I am have buttons like this:

```
<button type="button" class="img img_button_bla" onclick="...">Bla!</button>
```

The `img` class is:

```
.img {
display:inline-block;
border:0 none; 
background-image:url(/i_common/master.png) !important; /*regular sprite image*/
background-image:url(/i_common/master.gif); /*sprite image for ie*/
}
```

The `img_button_bla` class simply sets the width, height and background position.

What I am trying to do, is to style the button so the `Bla!` does not show on the button. I tried `text-indent:-9999px;` Which mostly worked, but not in IE7. For some reason, in IE7 only SOME of the buttons styled this way do not show up at all, but the space the button takes up is just blank.

I have also tried setting `line-height:0;font-size:0` which almost works except for a little black line that shows.

I also tried changing it to `block:display` which fixes the problem in IE7, but then messes up the layout since needs to be a inline-block.

I have tried searching around, but couldn't find any answer where it is using a button tag, a display of inline-block and using a sprite image.

Anyone have any ideas of what I could do to get this to work? I don't want to remove the text inside the button tag(there where no problems before because they used to be empty) for accessibility reasons and so the buttons will still show up in the mobile version of the site(basically no css on it).

Edit:

I was able to make an example file showing the problem, although in the example it doesn't work in IE8 either. Below works in FF and Chrome

```
<html>
    <head>
        <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
          #content {
              width: 980px;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
              padding: .5em;
              background-color: #fff;
              text-size: 1.1em;
          }
          .left {
              float: left;
          }
          .right {
              float: right;
          }

          .img {
              display:inline-block;
              border:0 none; 
              background-color:red; /*using color instead of sprite image for easyer testing */
              text-indent:-9999px;
          }
          .img_button {
              width:50px;
              height:25px;
          }
        </STYLE>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="left">
                <button class="img img_button">Hi!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <a href="" class="img img_button"> There</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, you can style `input type=submit` instead of having to rely on the buggy `button` element which is NOT recommended because in certain cases it passes the wrong information.

I have a snippet @ http://work.arounds.org/using-css-sprites-with-input-type-submit-buttons/ which you can base it off..

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get rid of me please">

<style>
input#submit {
border:0;
background:url(sprite.gif) no-repeat 0 200px;
text-indent:-999em;
line-height:3000;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
</style>
```

The line-height is for IE and text-indent is for modern browsers. You might need to specify a text-indent of 0 for IE since it doesn't apply text-indent offsetting.

Comment: How can the button element pass wrong information? Also, most of the time the button only calls a javascript function.

Comment: tried but didnt work. see my example that I posted. it works fine if you remove the content div, but not inside.

Comment: @meder I tried line-height, but that still doesn't fix the problem. As long as the text-indent line is there, they none of the button shows up at all in IE. Using just the line-height does make it work in IE, but the link that I try to style ends up being very long.

Comment: Did you try specifying a text-indent of 0 to IE only?

Comment: @meder How would I set text-indent to 0 for ie only? Also, I just noticed that link(I need to bookmark that site) But in that you changed it to block display instead of inline-block. That wont work for me site.

Comment: @Echo - conditional comments.

Comment: Figured it out, I added:   *:first-child+html .img{text-indent:0;line-height:3000;}

Comment: Cool, though it's better to use conditional comments instead of hacks like that.